# X-Frame-Options Allow-From is not working in some browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, security, clickjacking

I have added Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM=https://www.linkedIn.com in Apache configuration file to allow LinkedIn iframe for applying with the LinkedIn button but it is not working in firefox.
Web Server is Apache,
OS and Server is Ubuntu

Comment: Please provide some code and/or the errors returned to you.

Comment: i added 
Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM=https://www.linkedIn.com

Comment: i added 
Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM=https://www.linkedIn.com in apache.conf file.
There is no error as such. Apply with the LinkedIn button is appearing in chrome but in firefox, it is not showing, but when I am doing inspect element(firebug) in firefox the code is there but no iframe.